# Eigenvectors in a non-linear dynamical system

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Say if I have the non-linear system of equations $\dot x = \dots$ and $\dot y = \dots$.

I work out the equilibrium points, eigenvalues, and then the corresponding eigenvectors for the real eigenvalues. Say if the eigenvectors are
$$
\pmatrix{2\\1}, \quad \pmatrix{0\\1}, 
\quad\text{and}\quad 
\pmatrix{-2\\1}.
$$

Does this mean that the straight lines $y = 0.5x$, $y=-0.5x$, and $x=0$ are straight line solutions of the system of equations as in the linear case? Surely since the equilibrium points are non-zero then they would have a $+c$ so to speak.

Also, wouldn't these straight lines not remain straight lines and turn into manifolds depending on the nature of the non-linearity?

Comment: The eigenvectors are tangent to the stable/unstable/center manifolsat the critical point

Comment: I don't understand how a 2D system $\dot{x}=..., \dot{y}=... $ once linearized can have **three** eigenvectors.  Please give explicitly the system and the way you linearize it.